# Back Button Title changes when setting View Controller Title

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIViewController` A, embedded in a `UINavigationViewController` that pushes another view controller B on some action. Given the `UIViewController.title` of A is set to say "VC A", when B is displayed the back button has the title "< VC A" as expected. However if I were to set the title of B AFTER its `viewDidLoad`, the back button title gets changed to "< Back". If the title were to be set in `viewDidLoad` the back button title remains as "< VC A". Any thoughts on how I can set the title of B without it effecting the back button?

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "VC A"  
  }

  func doSomething() {
    // Instantiate ViewControllerB

    navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerB, animated: true)
  }
}

class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "VC B" // Works as expected
  }

  func doSomething() {
    title = "VC B" // Causes the back button title to change to Back from VC A
  }
}
```

I can create a custom back button with the title of the previous view controller in the navigation stack as a workaround but I'm rather curious as to why this occurs in the first place and a possible simpler work around.

Comment: It's rather easy to set *both* the title *and* back button text through code. But your question makes it rather difficult to help. Two pieces of constructive criticism: (1) Could you provide better details? Instead of "A" this and "< VC A" that, maybe use names that one can duplicate? (2) DO you have code that you've tried? I've both instantiated navigation controllers in code and overwritten titles and left bar buttons in code. But your "theoretical" question isn't detailed enough for me to actually help you. Thanks!

Comment: The code you have provided doesn't have any issue in itself. You might missing something in your original complete code. You can share it for better answer.